# Multiple screen shots not working in Python

Tags: python, screenshot

`Python` screenshot not working in `IDE python 2.7.14`. Not sure what I am missing in the code below:

```
    import pyautogui, time  
    x=l 
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()  
    while x < 4 :
        img.save("‪C:/Users/ABC/OneDrive/Desktop/Screenshots"+str(x)+".png")    
        x=+1       
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? What does it do that is not what you expect? This looks to me like it will slowly save a screenshot 3 times

Comment: `l` is not defined (maybe you meant `1`) and the actual screen capturing is outside the loop so you're saving the same picture.
Please consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you're incrementing x, you should do `x += 1` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui
import time

x = 1
while x < 4:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img.save("‪C:/Users/ABC/OneDrive/Desktop/Screenshots"+str(x)+".png")
    x += 1
    time.sleep(2)
```